# Even Numbers with Set Notation

Tags: analysis, recreational-mathematics, education

I am thinking about the many ways to write even numbers for set notation.

I found one that I havent been able to find any confirmations online.

$$\{x\vert x/2 \in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ Is this too simple of an answer?

I did find the other ways to solve but tried simplifying it.

Comment: I think
$$
\{ 2k ~|~ k \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$ would be more understandable

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why not use the set notation, $2\Bbb Z$ for the set of even integers? This is also used for $\Bbb Z$, the set of all integers.

Comment: You're correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this too simple of an answer?

It's not that it's too simple, but it's a little unnatural: For instance, if I extended division by $2$ to apply to some shapes so that, say $\triangle/2=-17$, then it would seem that $\triangle$ should be in your set $\left\{x\mid x/2\in\mathbb Z\right\}$. So your notation requires an underlying assumption that there aren't any weird definitions floating around.

It's a better habit to clearly write where each variable lives, as in $\left\{2k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$ (common) or $\left\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x/2\in\mathbb Z\right\}$ (not common, but avoids the problem I mentioned above).

You can see a couple of different-looking ways the set of even naturals might be written in set builder notation at [the Examples subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Examples) of [the English Wikipedia page for "set-builder notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Answer (score 1):

The notation $2\mathbb{Z}=\{2k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for the set of even numbers is common in number theory, group theory, abstract algebra, etc.

Moreover, $f(A)=\{f(k):k\in A\}$ is general notation (also used in functional analysis, topology, etc.).

For example, $2\mathbb{Z}+1=\{2k+1:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is the set of odd integers.